# How to call Android framework c++ functions in JNI?

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, android-source, android-framework

I need to call this function `virtual sp<IOMX>            getOMX();` in [/framework/base/media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerService.h](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerService.h#194) to get some information in Android. So I use **JNI** to do it. However, in the C++ code, can I call the Android framework C++ functions like `getOMX()` ? How to do? Thanks.

Comment: I find it usually the easiest way to make a proxy function in my java class (that I already know how to call) and do work / get a required object there. This way I don't need to be bothered calling constructors etc. Otherwise, JNI specs are quite straightforward on how to get an object of arbitrary Java class.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, thanks for your comment. But my question is, can I call any C++ functions from the Android framework or just the functions provided in the NDK?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Android API is mostly Java. Some C APIs are provided by NDK and you can use those. But you can't call Java APIs as if they were C++. Because they're not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use any APIs that are not "stable" in terms of the [NDK document](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/STABLE-APIS.html), you are playing with fire. But when it comes to `getOMX()`, the fire is not very hot.

You can get the headers from the AOSP source git, e.g.

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av
```

and `#include "frameworks/av/include/media/IMediaPlayerService.h"`

You will also need to provide the system `.so` files to linker, in this case - `libmediaplayerservice.so`. You can use command

```
adb pull /system/lib/libmediaplayerservice.so .
```

to get this library from an emulator or from a physical device.

Comment: But this header "frameworks/av/include/media/IMediaPlayerService.h" may depend on other headers and other headers depend on more headers. How can it work?

Comment: Yes, it does depend on few other headers, and even require more system (non-public) libraries, especially `-lutils -lcutils`, but the iterations converge quickly.

Comment: Note that in the end, after you have LOCAL_C_INCLUDES correct, you will likely have ` #include <media/IMediaPlayerService.h>`.